# In Django, how do I set a model that has a field with multiple instances of another model?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to writing Django models. I wanted to have a Person model, with each person having a variable number of positions worked.

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    positions = models.ForeignKey('Position')

class Position(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    summary = models.TextField()
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    currently_there = models.BooleanField()
```

How do I set it so that a Person can have multiple Positions?

Answer (score 1):

What you have is correct (you have one person with many positions).

I initially thought `ManyToManyField` but I see this is indeed a `one to many` relationship if the position are unique to a person.

Comment: Do I take the foreign key out in Person then that refers to positions? And also, if I am looking at a particular Person, can I see all their positions?

Comment: Yeah, Person should not have an FK to position. Position should have one to Person. Use an admin `Inline` to view them. Use person.position_set.all() to access the reverse FK via ORM. Read docs / have fun.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You already have it solved right there!

Reverse Many relations are returning a QuerySet, so the same methods you query the database with it used to fetch related rows.

ie.

```
# Grab a person
some_person = Person.objects.get(pk=2)

# Get the persons positions
positions = some_person.position_set.filter(currenty_there=True)

# Add a new position for this person
some_person.position_set.add(some_new_position)
```

A reverse set is named `modelname_set` by default and if you want a more friendly name you can add related_name to the Field

```
class Position(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="positions")
    ...

positions = some_person.positions.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

To the end of your Position class add:

```
person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

Basically this is a one-to-many relationship (One person may have many positions). You will have to rebuild your database (use south migration since syncdb cannot re-create from scratch) to create the foreignkey constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You have it right as some people have stated. When you use a foreign key, the model that you declare it on has a one-to-many relationship from the other model. In your case, a `Person` has a one-to-many relationship with `Position` meaning that a `Person` can have many `Positions` but a `Position` can only have one `Person`.

You can use the [RelatedManager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/relations/) to access `Positions` for a person

To access the `Positions` for each `Person` just do something like

```
harry = Person.objects.get(first_name="Harry", last_name="Potter")
harry.position_set.all()
```

To create a `Position` for a `Person`

```
harry.position_set.create(company="Hogwarts", summary="Student", ... )

etc...
```